# Check a PHP array for empty values and fill that particular key's value with default value if empty

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, conditional-statements, is-empty

I have to read a PHP array for empty values. If there are any empty values for any key, I just wanted them to be filled with some default value if empty.

**1. Is there any in built function to check if empty in an array and fill it up?**

(OR)

**2. What is the procedure to accomplish this requirement?**

Comment: `array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback ] )` call back is a simple function to check empty() that would provide you with a list of keys with empty values in them as a result array you can then populate

Comment: Dave as we know array_filter is to remove empty values. Just wondering whether it can able to list the empty value's keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_map()` can be used to apply a mapping to each array element.

```
$array = array(1, 0, 'foo', '', 'bar', NULL);
$default = 'DEFAULT';

var_dump(
  array_map(
    function($value) use ($default) {
      return $value ?: $default;
    },
    $array
  )
);
```

Comment: +1 Though you shouldn't use `empty` on variables that are guaranteed to exist. `!$value` will do just fine here.

Comment: You're right, this allows to use the ?: operator.

Comment: @deceze Why not empty?

Comment: @Alex [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @ThomasWeinert - bare in mind the use of the ternary operator without the middle part is only available since PHP 5.3

Comment: So are anonymous functions.

Comment: I've just used this, except that I've changed the return line to `return in_array($value, ["", null], true) ? $default : $value;`, as I want to include other falsy values in my final array.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a built in function which replaces empty values.

You could loop through the array, and if the value is empty, populate it.

For example

```
foreach($arr as &$val) {
    if(empty($val)) { $val = 'Empty'; }
}
```

Comment: Not too sure on the reason for the downvote - care to elaborate?

Comment: stop using loops like this thats why its a waste of resources when php has built in functions for doing exactly this that and you're flat out wrong when you say "there isn't a built in function"

Comment: @Dave if the 'built in functions' you're referring to is the array_map, take a look at this post. http://willem.stuursma.name/2010/11/22/a-detailed-look-into-array_map-and-foreach/ - `With big arrays, the peak memory usage of the array_map() function may be 2.5 times as much as the foreach loop.` `The fastest is the foreach construct. This construct can about 70% faster than an anonymous function, at least when there is not much to do within the loop.`

Comment: @Dave I disagree, there are no built in functions to do this. This answer is by far the simplest solution to the problem.

Comment: Try it with an array with 100k+ entries then come back and say this is efficient.  I don't rate array_map either just fyi

Comment: @Dave If you're going to run it with an array which includes 100K entries, you can expect a slight performance hit regardless. If you don't rate array_map, then it might be worth posting an answer which suggests a way of doing this which utilizes PHP's 'built in functions'.

Comment: @Dave `array_map` is just a loop in another form, plus  the overhead of repeated function calls, plus guaranteed data duplication instead of modification by reference. Yeah, much more efficient...

Comment: The difference is between an internal interpreter loop vs a scripted loop, the previously linked article is also many years out of date vs current though you're welcome to re-run the tests using a more current version of php and re-compare

Comment: I'm not going to even waste the time on proving such a point as I see no harm in using a foreach loop as opposed to an array map. I understand your point and until I have my own solid evidence I'm not going to argue it, but I felt you were making the point, just to make a point and that it wasn't actually a concern.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($array as $key => value){
    if(empty($value)) $array[$key] = "Some random value";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$ar=array(" ","test"," ","test2");
$ar = array_replace($ar,
array_fill_keys(
    array_keys($ar, " "),
    "hi"
)
);
```

Comment: Why "try this"? Why not explain what your answer does, why it is appropriate, and how you know that single-space strings are the appropriate targets?